# erropr publishing symbols during server build

Tags: debugging, symbols, build-server

I get a Partially Succesful build. The error is:

> SYMSTORE ERROR: Class: Server. Desc: Couldn't connect to server. Error
>   67: The network name cannot be found.  TF270015: 'symstore.exe'
>   returned an unexpected exit code. Expected '0'; actual '67'.

My symbols are supposed to be published on a share network drive, which the build service account has write access to. Yet, they are not published.

I don't know what to do to avoid this error. Could someone help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

turned out there was a typo in the path to the shared drive....
on top of that, pdb's were not generated at build because in the advanced option of the build tab in visual studio, debug info was set to none.